# RESTful URI Resource mutual exclusion based on query param in CXF

Tags: spring, rest, spring-mvc, cxf, query-string

In Spring MVC, for RESTful service, if URI and HTTP Method are same for two or more different resources, then they can be made mutually exclusive based on query params by using **NOT(!)** operator with Query Param  such as :

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/authentication", params = { "password", "!ssn" })
    @ResponseBody
    public SessionResponse userLogin(@Valid @ModelAttribute final UsernameAuthFormBean usernameAuthFormBean,
            final BindingResult bindingResult, final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response) {}



@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/authentication", params = { "!password", "ssn" })
    @ResponseBody
    public SessionResponse forgotPassword(@Valid @ModelAttribute final ForgotPasswordFormBean forgotPasswordFormBean,
            final BindingResult bindingResult, final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response) {}
```

**How can this be achieved  in CXF?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CXF and Spring MVC are not directly comparable. CXF is an implementation of  Java Api for RESTful services [JAX-RS](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/jaxrs-2_0-fr-eval-spec/index.html)

This operator `!` is not present in the specification and CXF does not implement it. You need to use different URIs

```
@POST
@Path("/authentication/userLogin")
public Response userLogin(@FormParam("") UsernameBean bean)


@POST
@Path("/authentication/forgotPassword")
public Response forgotPassword(@FormParam("") ForgotPasswordBean bean)
```

Comment: Actually we have an existing application and we have multiple clients who are using our existing endpoints, I cannot change the uri's but we have to migrate this application from Spring MVC to CXF, so is there any work around?

Comment: Then you need to implement the logic of the operation yourself: 1)define a unique method for uri `/authentication` 2) parse query params and select the target method 3) parse form params and call target method